# How to redirect user to login page if session expire in MVC 4 Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session

On _LoginPartial.cshtml I  have put following code which display username for user session:

```
<p>Hello , <span>@Session["username"]</span> </p>
```

but here I want to add one more condition that if session expire user must redirect to login pages and session must be abandon.

How to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: you add that in action

Comment: I have to redirect user to login page from view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this in View:

```
@{

if(Session["username"] != null)
{

<p>Hello , <span>@Session["username"]</span> </p>

}
else
{
Session.Abandon();

Response.Redirect("~/ControllerName/ActionName");
}

}
```

Comment: Actually I open a detail view in iframe so when I click on link button that Login page again display in iframe even I put this code on _Layout.cshtml view.